# How to remove white space between parentheses without affecting the string

Tags: objective-c

I have a string that looks like this:

> (
>
> ```
>  TEST STRING
> ```
>
> )

I want to remove the parentheses and the white spaces between the parentheses, but not remove the white space within the string.

Basically, I just want the string. I looked into trimming and replacing, but I don't think they applied here.

Any hint on how to go on about solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: of course they apply here. show some code. and define your requirements more clearly.

Comment: If `TEST STRING` was in double quotes, you can easily extract the string with `NSPropertyListSerialization` because the format matches the old NextStep format (which is still used for displaying arrays and dictionaries in Terminal.app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSString *originalString = @"( TEST STRING )";
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"( " withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" )" withString:@""];
```

Comment: /agree... his solution is easier to read as long as you know there is always a space.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using (NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSAnchoredSearch)
something like this (I'm writing code on the fly so its probably not correct.

```
  NSRange rng = [myString rangeOfString:@"([ \t\n\r]*"  options:(NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSAnchoredSearch)];
  NSRange rng = [myString rangeOfString:@"[ \t\n\r]*)"  options:(NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSAnchoredSearch | NSBackWardsSearch)];
  if ( rng.length && rng2.length )
  {
     myString = [myString substringToIndex:rng2.location];
     myString = [myString substringFromIndex:rng.location];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ()

```
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]];
```

And trim the white space.

```
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSCharacterSet *unwantedChar = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "@"\"-[}()\n "];
 NSString *requiredString = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unwantedChar] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, adding a explanation helps op to understand why/how it works.

Comment: i don't think there is any type of explanation required here.. because looking at the this line makes us understand how it works...